# Wildfly startup error

Tags: wildfly

I am using Java 1.8 & Wildfly 10.1.0 final version. While starting the standalone.bat ; I am getting the below error. I have reinstalled the Java several times but still the same issue persists. any help would be appreciated.

D:\Servers\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin>echo(!SERVER_OPTS!   | findstr /r /c:"-Djava.security.manager"  1>nul
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

It seems to get error while executing below line:
echo(!SERVER_OPTS! | findstr /r /c:"-Djava.security.manager" > nul

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `standalone.ps1` instead?

Comment: Many thanks. With Powershell it worked. Can you please explain the reason. :)

Comment: I vaguely recall seeing some mention somewhere that the `.bat` scripts are going to be deprecated - so they're probably not seeing much love at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Please use the PowerShell scripts, such as `standalone.ps1`, instead.

Various comments around the place, such as in [WildFly Issue 798](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-798) and [WildFly Issue 4743](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4743) suggest that the `.bat` scripts are not being as actively maintained as the newer `.ps1` scripts.